# MVC 3 on windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

i am developing a SAAS and want to use MVC on windows Azure. To get started i need how i can set it all up in Visual Studio 2010? Can i create the MVC 3 project locally and later integrate with Azure?

I will be using the cloud emulator

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Azure Tools update from Augustus 2010 has now integrated MVC3 support so there shouldn't be anything else you need to do besides making a Azure Solution and adding a MVC3 Web Role.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/08/03/announcing-the-august-2011-release-of-the-windows-azure-tools-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this recently. You can create an MVC3 web app just like you normally would, and then later, you can add a new Azure project to your solution and then add a WebRole for the existing MVC3 app. It worked without any issues.

Hope this helps.